# How to integrate Appdynamics to IBM Appconnect?

Tags: performance, apm

what is the bridge between IBM appconnect and appdynamics to connect apart from IBM agent , how to do it on windows ?

I tried connecting appdynamics which has all  metrics about my application need to connect my appdynamics to IBM Appconnect.